# How to get last 3 months or weeks or years or days in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this working code that gets the last 30 days.

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d').' - '.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 30 days'));
?>
```

I wanted to also to make it more dynamic such as:

```
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('from today to 3 months'));`
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('from today to 7 weeks'));` 
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('from today to 2 years'));`
```

Comment: what's the problem/error?

Comment: This is not a question, your code is working.

Comment: @rlanvin update my question sorry i didn't know it was working already, it was supposed to be a description

Comment: So you posted a question here with a code that was working, instead of simply TESTING the code and see for yourself. And now you edited your question with non-working code... for what exactly? To try to justify its existence? It's still not clear what was your question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 3 months')).'<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 7 weeks')).'<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 2 years'));
```

It's not necessary to specify `today` inside the `strtotime()` function.

To make it dynamic use `variables`, for example:

```
$amount = 5;
$field = 'months'; // or 'days' or 'years'...
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- $amount $field")).'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code looks just fine, but you can omit the 'today' part and just do:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months'));
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 weeks'));
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years'));
```

Comment: Thanks! same answer with @user2342558 Im accepting his answer he got it first

Comment: @Kenn This does exactly the same thing as the code in your question. What was going wrong originally and how does this fix it?

Comment: @iainn update my question sorry i didn't know it was working already, it was supposed to be a description

Comment: @rlanvin update my question sorry i didn't know it was working already, it was supposed to be a description

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer to get last dates from today :

```
<?php
  $today =  date('Y-m-d');
  echo $lastthereemonth = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-3 month',strtotime($today))); echo "<br/>";
  echo $lastthereeweeks = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-3 weeks',strtotime($today)));echo "<br/>";
  echo $lastthereedays = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-3 day',strtotime($today)));
?>
```